# How to download tweets for a phrase from twitter

Tags: java, twitter

I'm doing a project on Twitter data and want to be able to download tweets and the user who tweeted it for a given keyword. I want to download say around 5000 tweets for each such keyword, may be around 4 such words. How do I start with it ? I'm trying to found some resources online and many of them are in Python or they are outdated with old API. I want to use Java for downloading the tweets. Any suggestions on good libraries to do this or tutorials will be helpful. I also went through the Twitter API docs in twitter website and I do not have time at this moment to implement all myself using their API. I'm trying to find if there is a quick off the shelf way using any library.

Comment: Did you try Twitter's very own Java library? I imagine it would work pretty well... What results did you see when you did a Google search for Java Twitter libraries?

Comment: @MikeB, thank you for responding. I see Twitter4j at more places, but I'm unsure if it can do what I'm looking for. I see streaming API can download large number of trees, but as per my understanding, it will stream latest tweets but not the older ones and may be difficult to collect so many tweets for keywords I'm trying to search. Can you please let me know if Twitter4j can do what I'm looking for if you worked on it earlier ?

Comment: Twitter4j can definitely search by keyword. I don't know what the limit is on how many tweets it returns. How long would it take you the run a simple test query using it? Probably not very long, almost certainly less than the time that has passed since you posted this question.

Comment: @MikeB, I got the problem I expected. Using Twitter4J, I am making a query for a phrase and I get 100 records back. I am unable to avoid same 100 records again in next query with same key word, so that I can make a 5000 corpus and this is the reason I wanted an off the shelf library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using Twitter4J. At the time of this comment, I was able to download 72000 tweets per hour of a given keyword, legally.

Comment: I also realized we can download tweets in a simple way from NodeXL with out programming.

Comment: @StrawhatLuffy, for NodeXL ? There are no codes for NodeXL. Its all in GUI. For Twitter4j, they have examples in their repository. I have my code at https://github.com/santoshkt/twitter-sentiment-analysis if that helps you.